# Ubuntu locks up at "Started Clean php session files"

Tags: server, php, 17.04, 18.04

I am having an issue with my server box..

MSI Tomahawk B350 MB BIOS 1.60
AMD Ryzen x1800
64GB 3300 Ram
Samsung 960 Pro 1TB M.2 SSD
Plain Jane video card
500w Gold Power supply

I have tried Ubuntu 16, 17 and 18.. all do the same thing..  This is a fresh install, nothing running on the box except default LAMP..

It will run fine for 2 to 3 weeks, then freeze on me.. In the logs, it is always after:

```
May  2 03:42:24 SRV3 systemd[1]: Started Message of the Day.
May  2 04:09:01 SRV3 CRON[1718]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May  2 04:09:23 SRV3 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
May  2 04:09:23 SRV3 systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
May  9 07:17:40 SRV3 systemd-modules-load[557]: Inserted module 'iscsi_tcp'
```

Anyone else ever run into this or heard of the same issue?

Comment: I've been experiencing lockups, and sometimes I'll see these, but sometimes I won't. These often show up where there is no lockup. Mine are almost always when the screen is asleep.

Comment: I have the very same problem.  System locks in every few days. 

May 11 18:09:01 baby CRON[3453]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 11 18:09:01 baby systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
May 11 18:09:01 baby systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.

FREEZE.  THEN MANUAL REBOOT

May 11 18:30:23 baby keyboard-setup.sh[413]: cannot open file /tmp/tmpkbd.Kd5V8C